# What does $\delta$ mean here?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, machine-learning, neural-networks

What does $\delta$ mean here? If you help me at least one formula, then I'll try to do the rest.

[image]

Comment: Where do these pages come from? I'm assuming they are about machine learning.

Comment: Klaus Greff, LSTM: A Search Space Odyssey

Comment: I think, you simply have to add $\delta x$ to the quantity $x$ *in the next step*.

Comment: $δx$ is an infinitesimal variation of $x$. Which means mostly that it is so small that in the difference $f(x+δx)-f(x)$ you can safely omit all the higher order terms after $f'(x)δx$.

Comment: If I remember correctly, in Artificial Neural Networks, the $\delta$ just refers to the change to be applied to the next time step. E.g. $$y^{t+1}=y^t+\delta y^t.$$

Comment: How can I derive those formulas on the right from the equations on the left?

Answer (score -1):

Here $\delta$ means finite change in the variable in question.

Comment: How can I derive those formulas on the right from the equations on the left?

Comment: That wasn't your question.  I've answered the question you asked... correctly... and feel I should be given an accept ($\checkmark$) or at the very least an upvote (+1).